# Python: creating list of timestamps by minute

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out what the best way to create a list of timestamps in Python is, where the values for the items in the list increment by one minute. The timestamps would be by minute, and would be for the previous 24 hours. I need to create timestamps of the format "MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss" or to at least contain all of those measures. The timestamps will be an axis for a graph of data that I am collecting.

Calculating the times alone isn't too bad, as I could just get the current time, convert it to seconds, and change the value by one minute very easily. However, I am kind of stuck on figuring out the date aspect of it without having to do a lot of checking, which doesn't feel very Pythonic.

Is there an easier way to do this? For example, in JavaScript, you can get a Date() object, and simply subtract one minute from the value and JS will take care of figuring out if any of the other fields need to change and how they need to change.

Comment: `datetime` https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datetime is the way to go, you might want to check out [This Blog](http://effbot.org/librarybook/datetime.htm).

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print now
print now.ctime() 
print now.isoformat()
print now.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
```

This would output

```
2003-08-05 21:36:11.590000
Tue Aug  5 21:36:11 2003
2003-08-05T21:36:11.590000
20030805T213611
```

You can also do subtraction with datetime and timedelta objects

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
minute = timedelta(days=0,seconds=60,microseconds=0)

print now-minute
```

would output

```
2015-07-06 10:12:02.349574
```

Comment: Thanks, this comment was very helpful! Now I can just run this in a simple for loop and do something like

`list.append(now - (minute * i))`

where "i" would be a loop counter.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `datetime` and `timedelta` objects. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks! I had looked into the datetime module a tiny bit, but I must have missed timedelta. I had tried using datetime.datetime.now(), but it was not mutable, and I guess I just didn't look at the rest of the module carefully enough.